# Creating a class that serves both classic asp and ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic, vbscript

I have been tasked with migrating and upgrading our intranet web site from a Windows 2003 (IIS 6) server to a Windows 2008 R2 (IIS 7.5) server.  In the process I will be reskinning all of the ASP.Net applications to have the same look and feel as our classic ASP pages.

The website is based on vbscript (mostly) and javascript and the ASP.Net apps are written in VB.Net.

Over two years ago (and before I started working here) all of the classic ASP pages got a major overhaul and redesign.  At that time a framework was built for all of the classic ASP pages (which are the majority) but the ASP.Net apps were left looking the way the developer wrote them and are independent of the framework and I am the only developer here now.

What I am looking for is a way that I can construct a new framework (based on the existing) that classic ASP and ASP.net can both use without any problems.  I don't want to have to maintain two separate sets of code if I don't have to.

Most of the pages use the <% %> script tags to embed vbscript and I have learned that those tags do not work in ASP.net.

So far my feeble attempts to create this class has lead to errors and incompatibility. So before I waste any more time I thought I would throw this question out to the development community for advice.

Comment: Look into the MVC4 ASP.Net framework you can use it to quickly get things going.http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4 
Vbscript is no longer used in ASP.Net pages and should be updated to the newer technology.

Comment: Can you give us a more concrete example? I think I get what you're asking, but I'm not sure...

Comment: AnonJr, Hopefully I can explain this better.  I have existing classic ASP code that has a framework of ASP functions written in VBScript.  Each new web page uses this framework for several reasons but the biggest is page layout so that each page has the same look and feel.  In addition there are some ASP.net apps in VB.Net that are part of the web site but they do not have the same look and feel.  I want to modify those VB.Net apps so they look like the rest of the web site and I was hoping to incorporate the existing ASP framework into the VB.Net apps.

Comment: What I don't want is a Classic ASP version of the framework and a ASP.Net version.  Because if something changes then I have to make that change in 2 places instead of 1.

So I wanted to know if there was a way I could create a framework that could be used by both the Classic ASP pages and the ASP.net pages.

Marko informed me that VBScript is no longer used in ASP.net pages so that means a re-write of the framework code.  Fortunately VBScript is close enough to VB.Net that the rewrite won't be that difficult.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that my ASP.Net applications are all using .Net Framework 2.0 and they were written in Visual Studio 2008.  I have access to VS 2010 but I only have 2008 installed on my computer.  So I think this might be a game changer if I use MVC4.  There are earlier versions of MVC but I still think they are newer than VS 2008 and 2.0 .Net.  Plus I have never found anything, yet, that shows me that this will solve my problem.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that I am just going to have bite the bullet and recreate the framework using master pages and so forth for the .Net apps.  On the bright side the .Net apps only need a small handful of functions from the Classic ASP side and they can use the same CSS files to a certain extent.

Comment: You could have a single .NET codebase, and then compile one of them as a code library, which you can use to create a COM object that can be included into Classic ASP pages.

Comment: Thanks mikeyq6.  About a week after I posted this question I thought I would try that.  I created it as a VB.Net dll and I am still trying to work out the kinks.  I've created dll's before but never in a situation like this so I just hope I am doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

Open your VB.NET pages inside Iframes on classic ASP.
That will give your NET app look and feel of your favorite site while allowing you to maintain single set of code. And on top of that it will allow you to share data between VbScript and NET pages easier.

Iframes are supported by almost all browsers now days.

SORRY DID NOT SEE THAT the QUESTION IS ALMOST 1 YEAR OLD

Comment: That is a good idea.  My only problem is that I have to also make my Dot Net apps follow the same coloring and layout as the rest of the classic asp pages.  The dot net apps were created without any regard to the look and feel of the web site.